# Regex validation works without domain

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

So I have the following Regex URL validator:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+
```

It works perfectly well for my needs, except that it accepts urls without a domain for example `www.test` works.

How can I modify it to validate for a domain? (Any domain should be accepted not just `.com`

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/6siz406Iai)

Comment: If you want to match any domain, why use `[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` at the end, that will only match ASCII letters? Note that the lazy version will work the same as greedy one at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the last group in your regex mandatory as appearing two or more times:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}){2,}
```

As a disclaimer, and as @Wiktor will probably comment, you might want to use a regex pattern for validating URLs which already has been tested thoroughly.  While this answer may fix your immediate problem, there are most likely other edge cases which exist.

Comment: couldn't it be simplified adding case insensitive /i option removing A-Z?
i.e. /[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9](?:\.[a-z]{2,}){2,}/i

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this to account for unicode:

```
^\p{L}+\.\p{L}+(\.\p{L}{2,})+
```

> `\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}`: any kind of letter from any language.

So with this we match for a group of one or more letters (sudomain) followed by a . followed by a group of one or more letters (main domain) followed by any number of groups of . with two or more letters (domain suffix).